# How to correct "No value could be found for (Allowhotkey) that satisfies all lockdown requirements."?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, xenapp, citrix

After updating a Windows XP SP3 machine to Citrix Receiver v3.3, the user is unable to launch any published applications. The error they got is:

> No value could be found for (Allowhotkey) that satisfies all lockdown requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this for quite a while, and I eventually found a solution which involves disabling Citrix Lockdown. I found several link-bait-sites, which were of no use, and a few posts recommending a uninstall and re-install, which did not help.

Eventually after a lot of searching and finding garbage, I found this post [on the Citrix Forums by Simon Burbery.](http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=306555&tstart=0) In it, he recommends changing all of the `EnableLockdown` values from 1 to 0.

1. Export HKLM\Software\Citrix to a reg file
2. Find any `EnableLockdown` values (there are a few) and change from 1 to 0
3. Import the modified reg file
4. Exit Receiver completely
5. Launch Published App

I found about three of these values. I simply did a CTRL + F in `regedit` and changed the ones I found and restarted the receiver. I have yet to discover and side effects of this method yet.